# How do I get my changes to persist in Angular using 2-way Data Binding with an onDrag callback?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update a span's text after a call back function in Angular.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="onDragController">
         <div id="draggableArea">
        <div id="rectangle1" data-drag="true" jqyoui-draggable="{onDrag: 'dragCallback'}" data-jqyoui-options="{containment: '#draggableArea'}"></div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <span ng-model="rectangleOne">{{rectangleOne.leftOffset}}</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

And my controller is:

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop', 'ui.bootstrap']);

App.controller('onDragController', function($scope) {

    $scope.rectangleOne = {};

    $scope.rectangleOne.leftOffset = 'ASDF';

    $scope.dragCallback = function (event, ui) {

        $scope.rectangleOne = {leftOffset: '12345'};            

    };

});
```

If I toss an alert in my callback function then I am seeing that the leftOffSet is updated, but on my HTML page the {{rectangleOne.leftOffset}} is staying the same.

What am I missing here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$apply` in your `dragCallback` as follows:

```
$scope.dragCallback = function(event, ui) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.rectangleOne = {
            leftOffset: '12345'
        };
    });
};
```

This will update your `leftOffset` in the scope. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ejXJuPBcAUw8r14uyVKq?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much, I would upvote you but I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to better understand how Angular does two-way data binding. This blog post on [how apply works](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html), and why one would be motivated to use it, is pretty good.

**In summary, for your changes to `$scope.rectangleOne`:**

You can call `$scope.$digest()` every time you make a simple change like this. You need to do this so Angular knows to check if your bound data got updated.

Alternatively, you can use $scope.$apply, make the changes to `$scope.rectangleOne` inside a callback to `$apply`. It's doing the same thing, `$apply` ends up calling `$digest()` indirectly.

In code:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.rectangleOne.leftOffset = '12345';
});
```

Hope that helps solve your problem, and add a bit of understanding to what's happening behind the scenes!